# if/else statement in a for loop

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

I am writing individual results from a JSON array to a Parse.com database.  The attempted process is as follows:

For each result item in JSON array - search column **"EAN"** in class **"TestClass"** for content of **"JSON Result:EAN"**.

Then...

If **JSON Result:EAN** is present:  - ***console.log("Already In DB");***

Else

Write **JSON Result:EAN** to **Parse DB:EAN** & **JSON Result:name** to ***Parse DB:name***

The problem that I am experiencing is that if I have say 20 results with different names & EAN numbers - assuming that none are in the database, the below script writes 20 results to the database, but each write contains the name & EAN number of the last JSON result.

Here is a simplified version of my production code:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    var Products = Parse.Object.extend("TestClass");

    for (i in response.Products) {
        var name = response.Products[i].Name;
        var EAN = response.Products[i].EANBarcode;

        var query = new Parse.Query(Products);
        query.equalTo("EAN", EAN);
        query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                if (results.length > 0) {
                    var no = results[0].get("EAN");
                    var title = results[0].get("name");
                    console.log("ALEADY HERE: " + "[" + no + "] " + title);
                } else {
                    console.log('No matching records for' + name);
                    var newProduct = new Products();
                    newProduct.set("name", name);
                    newProduct.set("EAN", EAN);
                    newProduct.save({
                        success: function() {
                            console.log("Saved: " + name);
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log("Error: " + error.message);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
        });
    });
```

If I do not query the product & write it straight to the database (i.e: don't use query.find) & apply the code as follows, the database entries replicate the 20 different results as you would expect:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {

    var Products = Parse.Object.extend("TestClass");

    for (i in response.Products) {

        var name = response.Products[i].Name;
        var EAN = response.Products[i].EANBarcode;

        var newProduct = new Products();

        newProduct.set("name", name);
        newProduct.set("EAN", EAN);

        newProduct.save({
            success: function() {
                console.log("Saved: " + name);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("Error: " + error.message);
            }
        }),
    });
});
```

I cannot figure out why the lower code works, but it then does not when you enter the .find command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I get my arms around problems like these (multiple asynch operations within loops and conditionals), is to decompose to simpler operations and connect them with promises.  So, for example, lets have a function that finds a Product given an "EAN"...

```
function productWithEAN(EAN) {
    var Products = Parse.Object.extend("TestClass");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Products);
    query.equalTo("EAN", EAN);
    return query.first();
}
```

And here's one that creates a Product with a name and an EAN...

```
function createProduct(name, EAN) {
    var Products = Parse.Object.extend("TestClass");
    var newProduct = new Products();
    newProduct.set("name", name);
    newProduct.set("EAN", EAN);
    return newProduct.save();
}
```

Now, lets loop `response.Products`, look for matching Products in parse, creating if we don't find a match...

```
function findOrCreateProducts(response) {
    var promises = response.Products.map(function(p) {
        var name = p.Name;
        var EAN = p.EANBarcode;
        return productWithEAN(EAN).then(function(product) {
            return (product)? product : createProduct(name, EAN);
        });
    });
    return Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
        // return a proper array
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    });
}
```

**EDIT** Clarifying the data model a little, The following assumes a class called UserInventory, which has at a minimum two pointer attributes: one pointer to Product called "product", and one pointer to Parse.User called "user".

```
// return a promise to create user inventory for a user and product
function createUserInventory(user, product) {
    var UserInventory = Parse.Object.extend("UserInventory");
    var newUI = new UserInventory();
    newUI.set("user", user);
    newUI.set("product", product);
    return newUI.save();
}

// return a promise to create user inventory for a user and product, only if one doesn't exist
function findOrCreateUserInventory(user, product) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("UserInventory");
    query.equalTo("user", user);
    query.equalTo("product", product);
    return query.first().then(function(userInventory) {
        return (userInventory)? userInventory : createUserInventory(user, product);
    });
}

// return a promise to create a user's inventory from a remote api response
function buildUserInventoryFromRemoteSearch(user, response) {
    return findOrCreateProducts(response).then(function(products) {
        var promises = products.map(function(product) {
            return findOrCreateUserInventory(user, product);
        });
        return Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
            // return a proper array
            return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        });
    });
}
```

Call it...

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    var user = Parse.User.current();
    buildUserInventoryFromRemoteSearch(user, response).then(function(result) {
        // at this point, everything is done
    }, function(error) {
        // something went wrong
    });
});
```

Incidentally, at some time, it will be necessary to fetch a user's inventory...

```
function userInventoryForUser(user) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("UserInventory");
    query.equalTo("user", user);
    query.include("user");
    query.include("product");
    return query.find();
}
```

Hopefully you can study this to get the hang of the approach.  Key idea: is small, promise-returning functions that do logical chunks or work.

Comment: I'm getting the following console message: Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Comment: Actually, only using map, its just fine in pure JS.  edited.

Comment: Got it working!  Thanks.  I don't 100% understand whats going on (early morning in my timezone & time for bed).  I'll work out whats going on tomorrow.  Presumably, if I want to write another field to the DB (say price), I write `newProduct.set("price", price);` in createProduct & `var price = p.price;` on findOrCreateProducts ?

Comment: That's right.  And if there something else about it I can explain, feel free to ask and I'll edit.

Comment: Will do!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Going over the code with fresh eyes this morning & I have a few questions (a few new tools that I've not used before)... So am I correct in understanding that `return (product)? product : createProduct(name, EAN);` in findOrCreateProducts is basically saying if a product is returned from the search query - return it, else (I presume that is what the ":" does) create product in DB?

Comment: Yes, the `?` on that line is a ternary operator, it evaluates to the left side of the `:` if the condition before the question mark is true, otherwise it evaluates the right side.  What's being returned there is either the found product or a promise to create one.

Comment: Great.  Just read up a bit more on that.  Makes sense.  I've added `console.log("Written: " + name);` under `var EAN = ...` in the findOrCreateProducts function.  I'm struggling to work out how I would write `console.log("Already in DB: " + name);` if an entry is already present?  I have placed it in productWithEAN, but this just gives the last object 20 times, rather than each of the 20 objects.

Comment: To give you a better overview, what I am trying to eventually do is IF the product is not in Class A, write it to it.. then, create a pointer to Class B associating the product in Class A with the Parse User.  If the product is already present, there is no need to write to Class A, so can skip to the second bit.  Thinking further, I could do this after `$.ajax(settings).done...` but not sure if the write to Class A will occur before or with the write to Class B?  I'll do some more testing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99609/discussion-between-danh-and-mr-t).